# Get Latest Revision doesn't work

Tags: perforce

I've just set up Perforce on my home computer so that I can work at home without having to lug my work computer around.

I used the same workspace as the one I use at work, but when I try to get the latest revision, I don't get all of the files. Some subfolders are missing despite being mapped like this: `//depot/some_folder/... //My_Workspace/some_folder/...` `some_folder` has a subfolder `some_subfolder` but my workspace didn't pull that folder in for some reason... None of the other lines in "View" have anything to do with `some_folder` so I don't think they are the issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Perforce server tracks what files you pull in your workspace. This is done for speed, so when you do a "Get latest revision" it will only pull the files that need to be updated. Since you are using the same workspace, Perforce thinks you have them in sync already. You have 2 options.

1. Use p4 sync -f //files/... (If your using p4v, right click->Get revision, then in the options click the Force checkbox) This will tell perforce to sync everything to the latest revision. But then you will have to use this option at work and home, since Perforce will now think you have everything in sync, when really only the files at home are in sync.
2. Use a different workspace for home and work.

Comment: Unless you have a strong reason to need to share the workspace, separate workspaces are preferable. As George noted, using 'sync -f' will forego many of the speed advantages of separate workspaces.

Comment: You can also lose changes not checked in when you sync -f. I almost always use separate workspaces.

Comment: Always ALWAYS use a different workspace spec if you have a physically different workspace.  If you're trying to use the same workspace in two places and using `sync -f` to stomp on your own changes you might as well throw away your source control system and email files to yourself like a caveman.

Comment: Hmm, always thought caveman use pigeon mail.  Or git.

Answer (score 3):

In the GUI, instead of doing the get latest, try doing the context menu for "Get Revision...", and in that window that comes up, check the "Force" checkbox and give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

Create a different workspace to use on your home computer.  Do *not* try to use the same workspace on two different computers unless they're pointing at the same underlying filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to get the latest into a different folder. I renamed the folder from original workspace, but it did not work if I do a get latest. I created a different workspace, and it worked.

Comment: Do you have the folder locally already, and does it perhaps differ by only case from the folder name in the server?

Comment: Also, how are you doing get latest? From commandline, or the gui?

Comment: Yes, I have the folder locally already. What happened is that I checked in the code in pForce, however, someone complained after getting latest. So I have to get latest to see what is going on. There are some new change in my local. So I thought if I rename the folder and get latest should work, it did not. I did all in GUI.

Comment: If you have local changes and you want to get the latest changes from the depot, run the "resolve" command after you get latest to resolve your local changes with the depot changes.